# Optimize the sub query/ a better way to write the query

Tags: sql

Is there a way to optimize this below query??

```
SELECT 
 J.IRN, J.COMPLETION_DATE, J.FUNDS_MOP, J.SRC_IND, J.FUNDS_LOCAL_CURR, J.FUNDS_ORIG_CURR, J.FUNDS_LOCAL_AMT, J.FUNDS_ORIG_AMT, J.OBIREF_1, J.OBIREF_2, J.OBIREF_3, J.OBIREF_4, J.BBIREF_1, J.BBIREF_2, J.BBIREF_3, J.BBIREF_4, J.BBIREF_5, J.BBIREF_6
 FROM
(SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT * FROM 
(select * from
(select * from
(SELECT * FROM MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG WHERE NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.SRC_IND!='BK1' AND NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.SRC_IND!='ADV' AND NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.PROC_FLAG=1) A
where LTRIM(RTRIM(A.ORG_ID)) not IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401') OR LTRIM(RTRIM(A.ORG_ID)) is null) B
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(B.OGB_ID)) NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401') OR  LTRIM(RTRIM(B.OGB_ID)) is null) C
WHERE C.DR_ID NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401')OR LTRIM(RTRIM(C.DR_ID)) is null)D
WHERE D.CR_ID NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401')OR LTRIM(RTRIM(D.CR_ID)) is null)E
WHERE E.INST_ID NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401')OR LTRIM(RTRIM(E.INST_ID)) is null)F
WHERE F.BNF_ID NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401')OR LTRIM(RTRIM(F.BNF_ID)) is null)G
WHERE G.IBK_ID NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401')OR LTRIM(RTRIM(G.IBK_ID)) is null)H
WHERE H.BBK_ID NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401')OR LTRIM(RTRIM(H.BBK_ID)) is null)I
WHERE I.SND_BANK_ID NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401')OR LTRIM(RTRIM(I.SND_BANK_ID)) is null)J
WHERE J.RCV_BANK_ID NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401')OR LTRIM(RTRIM(J.SND_BANK_ID)) is null
```

Thanks

Comment: which sql database?

Comment: Oracle Database

Comment: please tag the database thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler version:

```
SELECT 
 IRN, COMPLETION_DATE, FUNDS_MOP, SRC_IND, FUNDS_LOCAL_CURR, FUNDS_ORIG_CURR, FUNDS_LOCAL_AMT, FUNDS_ORIG_AMT, OBIREF_1, OBIREF_2, OBIREF_3, OBIREF_4, BBIREF_1, BBIREF_2, BBIREF_3, BBIREF_4, BBIREF_5, BBIREF_6
 FROM
MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG
WHERE NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.SRC_IND!='BK1' AND NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.SRC_IND!='ADV' AND NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.PROC_FLAG=1
AND (LTRIM(RTRIM(ORG_ID)) not IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401') OR LTRIM(RTRIM(ORG_ID)) is null)
AND (LTRIM(RTRIM(OGB_ID)) NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401') OR  LTRIM(RTRIM(OGB_ID)) is null)
AND (DR_ID NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401')OR LTRIM(RTRIM(DR_ID)) is null)
AND (CR_ID NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401')OR LTRIM(RTRIM(CR_ID)) is null)
AND (INST_ID NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401')OR LTRIM(RTRIM(INST_ID)) is null)
AND (BNF_ID NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401')OR LTRIM(RTRIM(BNF_ID)) is null)
AND (IBK_ID NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401')OR LTRIM(RTRIM(IBK_ID)) is null)
AND (BBK_ID NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401')OR LTRIM(RTRIM(BBK_ID)) is null)
AND (SND_BANK_ID NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401')OR LTRIM(RTRIM(SND_BANK_ID)) is null)
AND (RCV_BANK_ID NOT IN('398601', '2296','399509','200111','302333','044401')OR LTRIM(RTRIM(SND_BANK_ID)) is null)
```

Comment: Can we not repeat the conditions, since they are same.

Comment: @Keerthi They are not the same. They are conditions on different fields. It does suggest that your data model is not great though.

Comment: The query is not filtering out data not in NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.SRC_IND!='BK1' AND NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.SRC_IND!='ADV'

But when just a part of it is executed 

SELECT 
 IRN, COMPLETION_DATE, FUNDS_MOP, SRC_IND, FUNDS_LOCAL_CURR, FUNDS_ORIG_CURR, FUNDS_LOCAL_AMT, FUNDS_ORIG_AMT, OBIREF_1, OBIREF_2, OBIREF_3, OBIREF_4, BBIREF_1, BBIREF_2, BBIREF_3, BBIREF_4, BBIREF_5, BBIREF_6
 FROM
MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG
WHERE NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.SRC_IND!='BK1' AND NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.SRC_IND!='ADV' AND NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.PROC_FLAG=1

gives records without BK! and ADV

Comment: You will need brackets around the OR statements, since otherwise the ANDs get evaluated first.

Comment: Right! I've added the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `AND` and appropriate logic.  There is no need to have the nested subqueries.

```
SELECT ets.*
FROM MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG ets
WHERE ets.SRC_IND NOT IN ('BK1', 'ADV') AND ets.PROC_FLAG = 1 AND
      (LTRIM(RTRIM(ets.ORG_ID)) not IN ('398601', '2296', '399509', '200111', '302333', '044401') OR LTRIM(RTRIM(ets.ORG_ID)) is null) AND
      (LTRIM(RTRIM(B.OGB_ID)) NOT IN ('398601', '2296', '399509', '200111', '302333', '044401') OR  LTRIM(RTRIM(ets.OGB_ID)) is null) AND
      (ets.DR_ID NOT IN ('398601', '2296', '399509', '200111', '302333', '044401') OR LTRIM(RTRIM(ets.DR_ID)) is null) AND . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the following will be more maintainable. As a proof of concept, here's [an sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd03a/2/0). You didn't tag the database, so this is Oracle-specific (using `from dual`) but you could easily rewrite to work with any DB.

```
SELECT MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.*
FROM MANTAS_STG.NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG left outer join
(
SELECT '398601' as num FROM dual
union all
SELECT '2296' FROM dual
union all
SELECT '399509' FROM dual
union all
SELECT '200111' FROM dual
union all
SELECT '302333' FROM dual
union all
SELECT '044401' FROM dual
) a
on
  LTRIM(RTRIM(ORG_ID)) = a.num
  OR LTRIM(RTRIM(OGB_ID)) = a.num
  OR DR_ID = a.num
  OR CR_ID = a.num
  OR INST_ID = a.num
  OR BNF_ID = a.num
  OR IBK_ID = a.num
  OR BBK_ID = a.num
  OR SND_BANK_ID = a.num
  OR RCV_BANK_ID = a.num
WHERE 
  NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.SRC_IND!='BK1' AND NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.SRC_IND!='ADV' AND NY_EGIFTS_TRANS_STG.PROC_FLAG=1
  AND a.num is null
```